# What is causing my incomplete location object error?

Tags: java, android, location

I am trying to create a Mock GPS service on an android app. I keep running into the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: incomplete location object, missing timestamp or accuracy?
```

I do not see how my location object is incomplete, as I do have both the timestamp and accuracy set in the object.

```
static LocationManager lm;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setMock(String mocLocationProvider, double latitude, double longitude){

        lm.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                1,
                2);


        Location loc = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
        Location mockLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider); // a string
        mockLocation.setLatitude(latitude);  // double
        mockLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
        mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
        mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mockLocation.setAccuracy(1);
        mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
        mockLocation.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(0.1F);
        mockLocation.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(0.1F);
        mockLocation.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(0.01F);
        lm.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
        lm.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, loc);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                 lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                double[] rand_coords = random_location_generator();
                rand_gen_lat  = rand_coords[0];
                rand_gen_long = rand_coords[1];


                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE );

                setMock(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, rand_gen_lat, rand_gen_long);
                setMock(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, rand_gen_lat, rand_gen_long);

                startMockLocationUpdates();


        return START_STICKY;

    }
```

As you can see, I have set my accuracy and timestamp, so why am I still getting this error? I hope I have provided enough information to make a proper diagnosis. Thank you.

Comment: You populate `mockLocation` but never actually use it - did you mean to use it in the `setTestProviderLocation` call ?

Comment: @Andy Thank you, I can't believe I missed that!